# How to save strings and other information in Pytorch model's buffer?

Tags: pytorch

I see there is `nn.Module.register_buffer()` method that stores information in model's `state_dict` and not in model's parameters.

Its definition is

`register_buffer(name: str, tensor: Tensor | None, persistent: bool = True) -> None`

It seems to only accept tensors as buffers.

Now I want to save some other things in my model, like my model's nickname (a string), the first start time of training, and other integer information, so that I can save and restore them easily.

Is it a good idea? Can I do it?

Comment: You can create attributes that have nothing to do with torch in your model class, they will never get processed as parameters, like `model.nickname`, ...

Comment: @PlainRavioli Thanks. Attributes are not saved and loaded automatically by `torch.save` right? So is it true that I have to save them and load them manually.

Comment: It depends, when you use `torch.save(model)`, it will save all the model, with all parameters, but it makes things a little rigid as it links your model to its class structure. Otherwise `torch.save(model.state_dict(), path)` only save the parameters. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html I understand why you wanted torch parameters for your additional info ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with buffers (which are non-trainable parameters). The advantage of doing this using buffer instead of an object instance attribute is that `torch.save()` will serialize it since it's part of the model's `state_dict()`. Here's an example of how to do this.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class ModuleWithNickname(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.register_buffer("nickname", torch.tensor([0]))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return x
    
    def set_nickname(self, nickname):
        # Convert characters in the string to ordinal values.
        ords = list(map(ord, nickname))
        # Set the buffer.
        self.nickname = torch.tensor(ords)
        
    def get_nickname(self):
        # Convert tensor to python list.
        ords = self.nickname.tolist()
        # Convert ordinal values to characters and join them into a string.
        return "".join(map(chr, ords))
    
x = ModuleWithNickname()
print(x.state_dict())
print(x.nickname)

print(x.get_nickname())
x.set_nickname("batman")
print(x.get_nickname())
print(x.state_dict())
```

Will print.

```
OrderedDict([('nickname', tensor([0]))])
tensor([0])

batman
OrderedDict([('nickname', tensor([ 98,  97, 116, 109,  97, 110]))])
```